# How to send raw-video data(YUV/RGB) data to surface on android?

Tags: surfaceview, virtual-reality, multimedia, android-mediacodec, encoder-decoder

I am working on an application where I need to send raw data(YUV/RGB) data on the surface, where I can see the video.

Right now what I am doing is, I am receiving an encoded frame(h265 form) and giving it to the decoding API to decode it further and then passing that decoded data directly to the surface API and this part is working properly so far.

Now what I wanted is, I want to further process that decoded data before passing to surface. I am not getting any support for the same. If someone can help me with passing raw data which is in the form of YUV/RGB to the surface then I would be really appreciated for the same.

Thanking you in advance.

Thanks,
Ronak